# Rails 3.1 asset precompilation - include all javascript files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I want Rails 3.1 to pick up more of my assets for precompilation. In particular, the default matcher for compiling files doesn't add `.js` files from `vendor/assets/javascripts`. I can just add the assets to the `config.assets.precompile` list, but this seems annoying. I don't want to refer to them in the `application.js` manifest, because I don't want them included in all pages.

In summary, any way to request that all `.js` files found in `vendor/assets/javascripts` get precompiled by `rake assets:precompile`, but without having them included in all pages?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`config.assets.precompile` accepts regular expressions and wildcard matching - so to ensure *all* js files get compiled, without specifying each by name, something like this should do the trick:

```
config.assets.precompile << '*.js'
```

Comment: I apologize for being a little daft here, but could you show an example of a adding a regexp to add all plain js and css but NOT all coffee or scss files? I've been trying to write one and it isn't working...

Comment: You probably want to overwrite what's already in precompile then: `config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css']`.

Comment: Although you'll probably want to add something for your images too.

Comment: @pat Actually, all images in `asset/images` directories are included. This is likely because they don't require any processing.

Comment: Though not mentioned by the documentation, if you look at the code of sprockets, you will find that `config.assets.precompile` also accepts `Proc`, which means that you can do some tricks like this: https://gist.github.com/1529093

Comment: Not sure why rake assets:precompile doesn't do this by default logically it should have done this.

Comment: @gouravtiwari21 They only precompile application.js and application.css as it's best practice to include other files using the `= require` syntax within application.(js|css).

Comment: @theodorton yes I agree and with that syntax it should automatically precompile other files, but the question clearly mentions that sometimes I do not want to include all js on all the pages, and as of now I don't see any provision for that other than answered by pat

Comment: @gouravtiwari21 I just skimmed through my layouts to check which javascripts and stylesheets were included, then added them as an array ['*application.js', '*application.css', '*welcome.js', '*welcome.css']. <answer type="opinionated">You'll normally have one master js/css file for each layout, so it's really not much work I'd say. Vendor assets should be required from your "master files".</answer> As for having a lot of JS on all pages, with proper caching and naming conventions for IDs and CSS classes it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Note that this causes a problem with bootstrap-sass: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915950/bootstrap-sass-undefined-variable-baselineheight

Answer (score 2):

I modified example given in [Rails config.assets.precompile setting to process all CSS and JS files in app/assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097993/rails-config-assets-precompile-setting-to-process-all-css-and-js-files-in-app-as) and here is my version, which takes all assets from /app and /vendor except partials (starting from _)

```
config.assets.precompile << Proc.new { |path|
  if path =~ /\.(css|js)\z/
    full_path = Rails.application.assets.resolve(path).to_path
    app_assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_path
    vendor_assets_path = Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets').to_path

    if ((full_path.starts_with? app_assets_path) || (full_path.starts_with? vendor_assets_path)) && (!path.starts_with? '_')
      puts "\t" + full_path.slice(Rails.root.to_path.size..-1)
      true
    else
      false
    end
  else
    false
  end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Precompile *all* assets, except those that start with underscore
config.assets.precompile << /(^[^_\/]|\/[^_])[^\/]*$/
```

Reference the 55minutes [Blog](http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/01/getting-compass-to-work-with-rails-31-and-32/) for the full explanation.

This will precompile any assets, not just JavaScript (.js, .coffee, .swf, .css, .scss)

Comment: This is great. Is there any reason I *wouldn't* want to precompile all assets?

Comment: @AlexChaffee if you're using something like SASS or the require comments to prepare 'bundles' of assets.