# bootstrap-sass: Undefined variable: "$baseLineHeight"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I've integrated bootstrap into my app using bootstrap-sass.  The app works fine on my local machine, but when I go to deploy via capistrano, I get this error:

```
Undefined variable: "$baseLineHeight".
(in /var/www/CollegeSportsBlueBook/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.0.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_accordion.scss)
```

When the capistrano attempts to run `assets:precompile`

I think this variable is throwing the error because it is the first variable in the first scss file that is attempted to be precompiled.

Something isn't loading up right.  Any ideas what it might be?

**Edit**

Full trace here https://gist.github.com/2233071

**Edit 2**

Added application.rb and production.rb to gist

Comment: Can you run `rake assets:precompile` on your localmachine?

Comment: Yea, but I have to run it and specify that I am on the development environment, if that matters: `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Have you changed `config.assets.precompile` at all?

Comment: @ThomasMcDonald - I don't think so.  I added application.rb and production.rb to the gist.  If you don't mind checking them out and making sure things look right.  Thanks.

Comment: @TylerDeWitt Yeah, you have changed it. Let me throw an answer together.

Comment: @ThomasMcDonald I saw on github someone else was able to get things working with the 2.0.2 branch.  Should I try that or is there a fix in my `config.assets.percompile` you'd like me to try first?

Comment: here i have given answer for it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911620/rails-bootstrap-sass-assets-compilation-error-undefined-variable-alert-padding/26998970#26998970

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You've edited your `production.rb` file so that Rails will attempt to precompile all CSS/JS files (line 48).

By default Rails will only precompile `application.css(.scss)`. By adding the wildcard selector to `config.assets.precompile` you are asking Rails to precompile *every* css asset in your application, including Sass partials. Naturally, this is probably not the behaviour you wish for.

```
# Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.js )
```

Rails will therefore iterate over each css asset, compiling them. It so happens that `_accordion.css.scss` is the first Bootstrap asset it comes across, and Rails will attempt to compile that first. `_accordion` isn't independent, and requires some files to be loaded before it, hence the error. It should never be compiled as a separate file anyway.

You need to change your `config.assets.precompile` to add only the additional files that you need aside from `application.css/application.js`.

Comment: This was exactly my problem as well and your solution solved it and gave me a clear answer as to where I messed up.

Comment: I don't have `config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.js )` anywhere and am getting the exact same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you. Same here. In Rails 4.2.1, the file to modify is now in /config/initializers/assets.rb

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the import of all your css is done in the proper order. For variables to work it needs to be one of the first few css files to be loaded.

This post/answer should help [Proper SCSS Asset Structure in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9138946/859762)

Answer (score 1):

Initially I had the similar problem 
*Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$alert-padding". problem* with this line in the `assets.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += [/.*\.css/]
```

Don't know why but for me it helped to change it to this line

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += [/^[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*\..*/]
```

After it the problem was solved and everything worked in production.