# How can I precompile all css files in a particular folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, assets, sprockets, precompile

To precompile all css files in a project I could add this to production.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile << '*.css'
```

But how can I add only css files in a particular folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all stylesheets into your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree dir_one
 *= require_tree dir_two
 */
```

Then they will be precompiled. I think this is the preferred way over using `config.assets.precompile`.

If you really want to use it, this SO question should help: [How do I use config.assets.precompile for directories rather than single files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613980/how-do-i-use-config-assets-precompile-for-directories-rather-than-single-files)

Comment: Thanks. This is the default, but it's no good if you want page-specific manifests though. This results in every file being thrown into a single compiled file. I need to break my site into separate manifests, and I don't want to have to add them individually. I'd rather have a single folder where my manifests live and where I know they will be precompiled.

Comment: Okay, look at the linked question, I think that solves it for you.