# In a Rails 4 app, how do I compile the jQuery Mobile button icons?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I am developing a rails 4 app with jQuery Mobile and using the jquery_mobile_rails gem which means I don't need to install any of the jQuery files. My problem is that there are no icons for the buttons. These are displayed in development but not in production. I assume that I just need to compile them but where are they and how can I do that?

Since I am not using jQuery Mobile files directly, I don't have the option to to store the icons below them. The gem works in development mode but not in production mode. Can I assume that the gems contain the button icons internally? If so, I am at a loss to understand why they don't work in production mode.

```
jquery-rails (2.3.0)
jquery_mobile_rails (1.3.0)
```

Comment: you need to put icons under `images` folder where jQM CSS file is placed.

Comment: There is no JQM file, I am using gems.

Comment: Have you added the following to your application.css manifest?      *= require_self
*= require_tree .
*= require jquery.mobile

Comment: Yes, all works perfectly in development, not in production - only the icons are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [known issue currently with Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/36) when precompiling assets per environment.

Try setting:

```
config.assets.precompile=true
```

in `config/application.rb`.

If that still doesn't work, try adding the following to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
```

I can't replicate the strange error you get when concatenating these files to `config.assets.precompile`. Can you [try the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097993/rails-config-assets-precompile-setting-to-process-all-css-and-js-files-in-app-as) instead (replace the line above):

```
config.assets.precompile << Proc.new { |path|
  if path =~ /\.(css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)\z/
    full_path = Rails.application.assets.resolve(path).to_path
    app_assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_path
    vendor_assets_path = Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets').to_path

    if ((full_path.starts_with? app_assets_path) || (full_path.starts_with? vendor_assets_path)) && (!path.starts_with? '_')
      puts "\t" + full_path.slice(Rails.root.to_path.size..-1)
      true
    else
      false
    end
  else
    false
  end
}
```

Comment: Do you mean production.rb? In either or both cases?

Comment: No, the bug means these changes to production.rb do not work, so you have to put them, for the moment, into `config/application.rb`. Until this issue gets fixed.

Comment: These 2 lines in application.rb produce <class:Application>': undefined method `+' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError) The first line is Ok but not yet tested in production.

Comment: config.assets.precompile=true by itself does not work. As stated above the second suggested line produced an error

Comment: Never seen that error before. And if you add the second statement to production.rb does it work? Not sure it will.

Comment: No error in production.rb in development. for some reason I get an error either way if i start Webrick in producton mode locally.

Comment: I get an error  undefined method `+' for true:TrueClass on   config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif application-print.css)

Comment: Added something else to try. Not sure why you are getting this error.

Comment: It works fine after I remove config.assets.precompile=true. The precompile string worked perfectly. Thanks!