# Rails 4 vendor asset images not being referenced from css files Heroku and S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a lot of vendor images under Vendor folder referenced from vendor css files.

I am using Heroku and S3 for production and thing like `background-image: url("../images/sprite.png");` is working in development but not in production as the image url points to S3 url.

It is not being precompiled either so not sure whether I should include this as part of precompilation of assets but I would like to stay away from this as I need to manually copy all image files across to `assets/images` folder and also change the reference in the `css` files by changing it to `scss` and also `asset_url` (which seems to be working fine)

Is there a way to not reference S3 url from vendor css files only

I'm also using `asset_sync` gem for uploading to S3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Precompile Assets**

Seems that you're experiencing a problem with [asset fingerprinting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark), and is an issue which can be resolved by `precompiling` your assets:

**[Heroku Tutorial on the subject](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline)**:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true

#cmd
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
git add. 
git commit -a -m "Your Commit"
git push heroku master
heroku run rake assets:precompile --app your_heroku_app
```

This will precompile all your assets (and should sync them properly)

---

**Asset Sync**

Having used the `asset_sync` gem with Rails & Heroku, we've found you've got to run the `precompile` command on `Heroku` itself (the last step in my above points)

The only way to check is to look your Amazon bucket -- if it's set up correctly, it should populate with the assets if you precompile on Heroku

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems like anything under `app/assets/images` folder is working but not in `vendor/assets/lib/something/images` for example. So I was wondering if it's possible to add them for precompiling instead of me having to copy those images across `app/assets/images` directory manually

Comment: Why not try this: `config.assets.precompile += ['your/dir']`. I'm not sure if it will work for items outside of the asset pipeline (`/assets`), but it's what you'd need to make this work. There's a good reference here for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097993/rails-config-assets-precompile-setting-to-process-all-css-and-js-files-in-app-as

Comment: @RichPeck Should I do this every time I add new assets to my project, right?