# Rails assets is confusing scss file for css

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some third party modules in my `node_modules` folder in my Rails app.

I want to compile them as assets. So I'm doing:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')

# Only compile js and css files.
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile.push(Proc.new do |path|
  puts path
  File.extname(path).in? [
    '.js', '.css'
  ]
end)
```

In one of the node_modules, there is a file `node_modules/somelib/src/style/main.scss` (notice .scss). However, for some reason, this file is still being included in the assets. The output from the above `puts path` statement prints:

`node_modules/somelib/src/style/main.css`

What! Why is it changing it to .`css` when it is clearly a `.scss` file?

The reason I need to disable this behavior is that the .scss file in question has an `@import` statement that Rails doesn't know where to find (rightfully so, it wasn't meant for Rails's eyes.) So it throws an error. I need to exclude this scss file.

Comment: May be you have some other rules in your `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile` You just add your path to the end of array.

Comment: better way to force js and css only compilation is 

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile = %w(*.js *.css)`

Comment: here some examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097993/rails-config-assets-precompile-setting-to-process-all-css-and-js-files-in-app-as

Comment: Same thing..Rails seems to convert the scss file to css _invisibly_ before it reaches this point.

Answer (score -2):

Sass is the most mature, stable, and powerful professional grade CSS extension language in the world. For more details - https://sass-lang.com/

I think stylesheet name extension may be change through this gem - https://github.com/rails/sass-rails