# Stack Level Too deep error with rails assets:recompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

I have been up fighting with this error for a while now, whenever I run rake assets:precompile in my application, I get the error *stack level too deep*, I've tried changing the version of bootstrap and ruby, but no head way. 
Here is my current setup:

- Ruby 2.3.2
- Rails 4.2.5.2
- bootstrap-sass 3.2.0.2, have tried 3.3.7 too
- sass-rails 5.0.7

Any help on how I can handle this it highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe there's something in your initializers that causes infinite recursion? What about other rake tasks or rails console, do they work correctly?

Comment: Everything else seams fine apart from compiling the assets.. I can access the console ..

Comment: Am seeing it coming from a point where I call image_path in rails, hope that helps

Comment: Any backtrace for that error?

Comment: The solution here might just make it for me, waiting for response from my supervisors.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097993/rails-config-assets-precompile-setting-to-process-all-css-and-js-files-in-app-as