# How do you speed up rails-3.2.3 asset pipeline on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

I notice css/js download of my site homepage on Heroku, takes a second and half more or less. I'm curious if some of you guys, has same experience or should I expect faster responce.

http://gitwatcher.com/assets/application-61efaf20532302f93b6c79d976861884.css:

```
GET application-61efaf...6c79d976861884.css 200 OK gitwatcher.com 19.4 KB 75.101.163.44:80  
476ms
```

http://gitwatcher.com/assets/application-66c036d6d06705744603507b085afdf4.js:

```
GET application-66c036...603507b085afdf4.js 200 OK gitwatcher.com 62.7 KB 75.101.163.44:80  
1.24s
```

also DNS responce seems quite low, about 1.08s.

Could you please share your experience or suggestions ?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you're precompiling your assets? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278029/rails-3-1-asset-precompilation

Comment: @Kevin Bedell just js actually :  config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.dataTables.min.js DT_bootstrap.js )

Comment: @apneadiving did you mean this way https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31 ?

Comment: @LucaG.Soave: yes + see other details in John's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed "[Using a CDN Asset Host with Rails 3.1](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31)" as suggested but things are going even worst now:

CSS are served ~3.5 times slower then before :

```
GET https://gitwatcher-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/application-82e153501de8c4032d1565a3e8adffc1.css

200 OK
    ,
gitwatcher-assets.s3.amazonaws.com

166.2 KB

178.236.4.193:443


1.62s
```

while js takes 1.7s vs 1.25 :

```
https://gitwatcher-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/application-66c036d6d06705744603507b085afdf4.js

200 OK

gitwatcher-assets.s3.amazonaws.com

198.6 KB

178.236.4.193:443


1.7s
```

even worse, all png images are now downloaded from S3 with a media of 1.5s each one ( more or less in parallel of course ), resoulting in a ~4s overall time for the home page (bad), which is more or less as before, but now DNS overhead is light ( ~ 1/3 ). Than I guess static asset served via S3 is slower than directly served by heroku .... !?!

I'll leave it like that until I'll have some more analytics, but I wonder if some one can share his experience and performance data about serving static assets this way, to compare with.

ALL measures here are taken via FireBug client side (firefox: 93.34.152.23) and the bucket is in Ireland.

Comment: I learned to not use EU buckets, but distribute the US one content via CloudFront.

Answer (score 3):

Use the asset_sync gem to have your assets pushed to S3 on deployment. Ideally you don't want your processes at Heroku serving assets, leave them to process Ruby - have all your static assets on S3 and/or Cloudfront or similar.

Comment: please see my post ( as new answer )